# How jealous is Lolth?

Tags: dnd-4e, forgotten-realms, lore, religions-and-deities

I’m making a drow, and part of his backstory is that he learns to worship another goddess; the platinum dragon Bahamut. You have to be L/G to worship him, but Lolth is still a part of drow life, so could he worship both without being attacked by her or her followers? (It doesn’t really matter but this is 4e)

Comment: `You have to be L/G to worship him` I play 5e not 4e so I may be wrong, but I don't think you *have* to have a specific alignment to worship a specific deity.

Comment: While the answer below is a good description of Lolth, this question feels a little unclear.  These deities are diametrically opposed.  Lolth is chaotic evil.  How/why would your character worship both?  Are they pretending to worship one while secretly following the other?  If they are actually a genuine believer of Lolth's philosophy, I dont see how they could simultaneously worship Bahamut?  If they believe in the ideals of Bahamut, then wouldnt they be strongly against the rather psychopathic amorality of Lolth's servants?  Apologies if this is meant to be a purely mechanical question.

Answer (score 15):

[The Forgotten Realms wiki page on Lolth](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Lolth) states:

> She drove the drow into heavy infighting under the pretense of culling the weak, while her real goals were to hold absolute control over the dark elves, **prevent the rise of alternative faiths or ideas**, and avoid complacency (even though she found amusement in the strife that plagued her followers' communities).

so: (1) no, generally speaking Lolth would not be tolerant of your character's worship of a different god; but (2) your character is still likely to be attacked by Lolth's followers, just out of general spite, *even if your character worships Lolth exclusively*.

Comment: She's also flat out unambiguously *evil*. She'd hate Bahamut on general principles even if she were open to "her" people worshiping other deities.

Comment: Should be noted that while Lolth and Bahamut exist in both, the 4e default setting which OP is probably uaing is not Forgotten Realms but Points of Light.

Answer (score 6):

### Lolth is *legendarily* jealous.

As in "once upon a time she betrayed the gods and stole the drow for her personal use". Assuming your DM's running the default 4E campaign setting they put the books out for, and not, say, the *Forgotten Realms*, which has its own wrinkles. Here's a fun little bit from *Underdark*, p.73:

> The drow are all but monotheistic, recognizing no other divine beings as true gods. Bahamut, Moradin, Torog, and the rest are acknowledged as real, and powerful, but as beings of lesser status. **Those caught praying to or drawing divine power from false gods are consigned to the Fane [of Lolth] as sacrifices.**

Of course, that's only true for the drow who count themselves part of proper drow society and its endless games of spider-and-also-spider. An outcast can fall in with any god, because what are they going to do, kill you twice?